# Recursively search for files starting with specific string created after date

Tags: r, date, file-search

I am trying to find certain files with the following pattern created in 2022. Right now my approach is to use `list.files` to find the paths and then use `file.info` to find the dates and filter them using that information. The file paths are found in a decent amount of time and returns 2923 elements. However the file info is taking forever. Is there a better way to approach this?

```
workdir2 <- "C:/Users/<user>/folder"
setwd(workdir2)

filelist <- list.files(pattern='^DATA_.*\\.xlsx$', recursive = TRUE,  full.names = TRUE)

fileinfo <- file.info(filelist)
```

Comment: what exactly do you need from each file? ie the dates of creation? modification?. You should consider working on one file at a time, check how long that takes, then you can run them in a parallel manner

Comment: the ctime as I said above and I need times to know which to work on

Comment: On my system, `file.mtime` is 5 times faster than `file.info`. Maybe if you first filter by creation time, then `file.info` gets the ctime of a smaller vector, then parallelize, like @onyambu said.

Comment: thanks the file.mtime was so much faster and I can go from there

Comment: I don't know if this is faster but you can try the fs package: `library(dplyr);
library(fs);
path %>%
  dir_info(recurse = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::filter(grepl(2022, modification_time))`